# Close two form by one click?

Tags: c#, forms

I'm working on project with sign in feature

When I run the project there is a form (`form1`) run the sign in .
after i click on login button build another form (`form2`) - It's the form of my program .
and made the first form (`form1`) hide .

The problem is when I press at the X button in form2 it's close but the form1 it's still running .

I tried to close the `form1` instead of hide ... but this will close `form2` before launching

In `form1`:

```
this.Hide();
Form2 x = new Form2();                 
x.Show();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could subscribe to the child forms `FormClosed` event and use that to call `Close` on the parent form.

```
x.FormClosed += new FormClosedEventHandler(x_FormClosed);

void x_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
{
    this.Close();
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I think you have your forms around the wrong way.

Form1 sould be your app and shold show Form2 as a dialog when it first loads, then when it closes you can process the result and decide wether to continue or close the application.

Something like:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        Load += new EventHandler(Form1_Load);
    }

    void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Form2 myDialog = new Form2();
        if (myDialog.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel)
        {
            // failed login
            // exit application
        }
        // all good, continue
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, in the log in button if access is granted

```
private void logInBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Form2 frm = new Form2();
            frm.ShowDialog();
            this.Hide();
        }
```

then in form2 if you want to exit

```
private void exitBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
```

hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

You go to your form2 then in the event of the form look for FormClosed.

Put this code in your eventhandler:

```
private void Form2_FormClosed(object sender, FormClosedEventArgs e)
    {
        Application.Exit();
    }
```

FormClosed is the event whenever the user closes the form. So when you close the form put a code that will exit your application that is -applicationn.exit();-

Hope this will work.