# Closing an active form from another FormClosed event

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a class with several functions, within all of these functions I have a try catch and in a catch I start a new form to show the error. Like this:

```
Program.erro = exception.ToString();
Error NewError = new Error();
Error.ShowDialog();
```

But I need to be able to close the current form FormUpdate as an example whenever I close the error form.
I've put this line of code in the error's `FormClosed` event:

```
UpdateOrca.Update.ActiveForm.Close();
```

> "Update" is the open form that needs to be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just make use of the `using` statement and then when your error dialog has been closed, the rest of the code will execute.

```
using (Error NewError = new Error())
{
    NewError.ShowDialog()
}
this.close();
```

You can then remove the code that you have placed in `NewError`'s closing event.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148925/close-two-form-by-one-click) SO question creating close event of the child form in main form, and calling this.close() inside it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You should pass the calling form instance to the dialog form. `.NET` allows you identify the owner form of the openning form.

For example; You can open a popup like;

```
Dialog frmDialog = new Dialog();
frmDialog.ShowDialog(this);
```

Then; in the popup form you can listen the form_closing event like;

```
private void Dialog_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e)
        {
            if (this.Owner != null)
                this.Owner.Close();
        }
```

Hope it helps.